# Specify limits to Date axis that crosses the new year

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I have this dataset I am working with where I am plotting monthly 
summaries. A problem I have encountered in ggplot2 is to let the x axis go from say month 10 to 12 and then continue onwards with months 1 to say 4. In the example below I show this 
with a 20 year dataset where I remove months May to September and plot the rest.

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
mon=seq.Date(from=as.Date("2000-01-01"),to=as.Date("2019-12-01"),by="month")
val=rnorm(length(mon))
dd=data.frame(mon,val)
ddsub=subset(dd,month(mon)<5 |month(mon) >9)
ggplot(data=ddsub,aes(month(mon),val,group=month(mon))) + geom_boxplot() + 
      xlab("Month") + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1:12))
```

[image: Monthly data with gap]

What I would like is for the x axis to start in Oct and to continue past the end of year to Apr.
Since `month(ddsub$mon)` returns a numeric resulting in a continuous horizontal axis, I have not found any neat way of breaking the ascending numerical order.

My only solution is do define the months as factors that I then reorder in the right way

```
mon_factor=as.factor(month(ddsub$mon))
ddsub$mon_ahead=reorder(mon_factor,rep(c(4,5,6,7,1,2,3),20))
ggplot(data=ddsub,aes(mon_ahead,val)) + geom_boxplot() + xlab("Month")
```

[image]

While this works, I don't find it an elegant solution. It is cumbersome to have to
define a new month variable and then reorder it.

Does anyone know if there is a way of working with the Date-objects directly and define
the limits of the axis so that it begins in Oct and ends in Apr ?

Comment: for an edit: there's typo in the initial chunk; should read `scale_x_continuous`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid creating a factor, you can do it on the fly with the modulus operator and creative labels:

```
  ddsub %>%
    ggplot() + 
      geom_boxplot(aes(x = (month(mon)+2) %% 12, y = val, group = month(mon))) + 
      xlab("Month") +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0:6),labels = month(c(10:12,1:4), label = T))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is succinct (and elegant).

Answer (score 3):

I think using a factor will be simplest here, and you can automate the ordering using a helper column like `mo_FY` below, which makes October month `1` of the fiscal year. I like the syntax of `forcats::fct_reorder` to establish the ordering.

```
ddsub$mo_FY = (month(ddsub$mon) + 2) %% 12 + 1
ddsub$mon_fct = forcats::fct_reorder(factor(month(ddsub$mon)), ddsub$mo_FY)                 
ggplot(data=ddsub, aes(mon_fct, val)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  xlab("Month")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Did not know the forcats::fct_reorder function.